# How to change values in jsoncpp object

Tags: c++, json, object, jsoncpp

I am trying to change values in my jsoncpp object. I found multiple solutions for jsoncpp array, but so far none for jsoncpp object. What I am trying to do is:

```
void saveAllValues(FIELD **field, Json::Value node, unsigned int* i){

    for(Json::ValueIterator it = node.begin(); it != node.end(); it++) {
        if ((*it).isObject() || (*it).isArray()) saveAllValues(field, *it, i);
        else {
            std::string value = field_buffer(field[*i], 0); //get value from ncurses field
            *it = Json::Value(value);
            (*i)++;
        }
    }
}
```

So far this code does nothing. How can I change value of current node?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a C++ typo/misunderstanding, not a JsonCpp problem:

```
void saveAllValues(FIELD **field, Json::Value node, unsigned int* i){
```

You took the node *by value*.
So no changes to it are going to have the slightest effect in the calling scope.

Take a reference to an existing node instead:

```
void saveAllValues(FIELD **field, Json::Value& node, unsigned int* i){
```